# Duplicate columns of a bed file to produce another bed file

Tags: awk, cut, columns

I have a bed file genome_cov.bed specifying the coverage of a genome at every position on the genome. The columns are; scaffold, position, coverage.

```
scaffold_1      1       0
scaffold_1      2       0
scaffold_1      3       32
scaffold_1      4       34
scaffold_1      5       34
scaffold_1      6       39
scaffold_1      7       39
scaffold_1      8       53
scaffold_1      9       58
scaffold_1      10      60
```

I would like to produce another bed file that duplicates the second column.

When I use cut -f, I cannot duplicate the column, and when I use the awk command :

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$2,$3}' genome_cov.bed > genome_cov2.bed
```

it does not produce a bed file and ends up looking like this:

```
scaffold_1 1 1 0
scaffold_1 2 2 0
scaffold_1 3 3 32
scaffold_1 4 4 34
scaffold_1 5 5 34
scaffold_1 6 6 39
scaffold_1 7 7 39
scaffold_1 8 8 53
scaffold_1 9 9 58
scaffold_1 10 10 60
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either set the *output field separator* to the tab character:

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$2,$3}' OFS='\t' genome_cov.bed
```

or use `printf` to specify the format explicitly

```
awk '{printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n",$1,$2,$2,$3}' genome_cov.bed
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Both of those worked. Please could you explain what `"%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n"` is doing?